# Max Size of unique JMSMessageID

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic-10.x

I am using JMS for one of my requirement in my application.I want to store each message unique ID (actually MDB's) in the database through which I am fetching the unique ID using the below code:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            id = msg.getJMSMessageID();             
        } catch (JMSException e1) {
        } 
}
```

From the above code I have message unique ID,but what I would like to know is what could be the Max Size of any message so that I need to configure database accordingly.

I am using Weblogic Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum length of JMS Message ID is defined by the JMS provider.

At a bare minimum you would need to consult your provider documentation in order to determine what the appropriate size should be for your database column. For a more portable solution you should set it to a fairly large value - that way you are not relying on any one vendors JMS implementation to dictate the size of the column.

I would say that for the most portable solution you should not store the JMS Message ID at all, if you can avoid it. You could always generate your own ID for the message and store that instead,  which would allow you to define the correct column length for your purposes.

Comment: Actually I want to update database for that particular Message when the process is completed due to which I am storing the Message ID in the database.Taking your suggestion to create my own ID can I set that unique ID in Message.setJMSMessageID(XX) and use that ID in MDB class by calling Message.getJMSMessageID()?

Comment: Do you have to communicate with another system that relies on this ID? Or are you somehow recording the ID elsewhere? Because if not you can simply store your own unique ID for the message and then use that throughout the processing phase.